# How to Use Google cloud Datastore with C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to google cloud datastore and trying to access 'KIND' and save to with C#. I have searched the documentation available on google cloud but did not find how to access data on google datastore and save to. I am able to authenticate.

There is proper documentation for JAVA, NODE.JS, GO and PYTHON but not for .NET.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can totally use C# to access google cloud datastore.

This sample shows you how:
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore
Here's a direct link to the code:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-dotnet/blob/master/aspnet/2-structured-data/Models/DatastoreBookStore.cs

To search by Kind:

```
    var query = new Query()
    {
        Limit = pageSize,
        Kinds = new[] { new KindExpression() { Name = "Book" } },
    };
```

To create a Key with the specified Kind:

```
    public static Key ToKey(this long id)
    {
        return new Key()
        {
            Path = new KeyPathElement[]
            {
                new KeyPathElement() { Kind = "Book", Id = (id == 0 ? (long?)null : id) }
            }
        };
    }
```

More documentation is coming soon.

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyRennie. This is helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote a mini .NET ORM for the Google Datastore:
https://github.com/NoGame/GoogleDatastoreORM

You might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for your ORM project. I want to use Datastore with Xamarin Forms app. Do you have anything related?

Comment: I encountered "Page not found"

Answer (score 0):

The actual API Reference is almost impossible to find. I eventually tracked it down here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb.html#Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_DatastoreDb_Create_System_String_System_String_Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_DatastoreClient_

Hopefully this helps someone looking for all of the documentation.